Overwhelmed when processing questions in staging ground
I've tried to process some new questions in Stack Overflow's staging ground, but quickly got overwhelmed.  Most questions are out of my comfort zone to triage (due to not knowing the underlying tech used), and for the ones left over I'm either reluctant to press accept since it might be a duplicate (how to find out?), potentially off topic (config problems should go to superuser I suppose?), or already declined where I see room for improvement but where I hesitate to take action, since I know I'm often too lenient and try to help out people anyway.
So I processed lots of questions with a 'Skip', apart from one where I felt reasonably comfortable the question was genuine, of a high enough quality and not off-topic.  So I felt pretty useless afterwards.  I then went to the staging ground review history and saw some other users working through the queue in parallel with me, and they mostly just declined most questions (for various reasons, but mostly off-topic).
Are these other persons just all-knowing gods and should I git gud on all possible tech out there so I can give fast and appropriate feedback too?  Or should I just not feel intimidated by the process and the possible consequences of mislabeling a question?  Or should I just stick to a tag I'm most familiar with and only review questions for that tag?

Don't fall into the trap of looking at off-topic reviews from other reviewers. Off Topic is a reason misused quite a lot in the SG.

Reviewing in the Staging Ground: A practical guide might be helpful for picking which review option to use. Also, if someone reviews many questions very quickly, that might be suspicious and worth checking...

Try to filter by the tags you are interested in - this way you the questions will be closer to your comfort zone.

You seem to have skipped this one, for example? How uncomfortable did you feel about what feedback you could have made?

@dan1st I'm reading that guide now -- thanks; it is really helpful

@francescalus Yeah, after a while I started to auto-skip questions where I didn't even know what the tags meant :)  Looking at that one again I think it is OK?  It's clear and concise, though it lacks info on what the user already tried?  I was tempted to 'rescue' this one by altering the title to "Advice on improving Python code", but then thought it would be better served on Code Review.  So many options...

If you're starting in the SG, then working on your watched tags is probably a much safer bet. Unfortunately [so] currently refuse to send the majority/all of content that should go to the SG to the SG, so the volume you see may be (very) low, which makes onboarding for users like yourself hard. It's very much, in my opinion, a chicken and the egg scenario; [so] want more user engagement before they open the flood gates, but user engagement is low because the volume in the SG is (far) low(er than it should be).

@ThomA I've just now filtered the queue by tag (C++ as a starter) and looking at already triaged entries to get a feel for what's appropriate.  All questions in the filtered list are already triaged so there's not much left to do, but for this tag there are fortunately quite a lot of recent entries -- then again this tag is also one of the busier ones I assume.

@CarlColijn Please don't assume that other reviews are "good" (especially when it comes to off-topic and sometimes approvals). The main tool in the Staging Ground is "Requires Major Changes". If you want to discuss specific reviews/how to review questions, you can also check the Staging Ground Discussion/Support chatroom.

@dan1st Noted, thanks.  But this one e.g. seems like a good, constructive back-and-forth example, right?

Mini-feedback, but in my Opinion, "Advice on improving Python code" would have been a terrible Title, the current/original one ("How to draw a 3x3 board cell with raw numbers 1-9 written inside the cells without repetition of codes"), apart from missing a question mark, is a much-much better one, because descriptive and containing useful Keywords about its content without even opening the Question...

@chivracq The reason for my title suggestion is that the questioner seems to be asking about how to draw a 3x3 board, but the code he has already does that.  Instead he really wants to know how he can reduce the repetitiveness of his code?  The feedback he got was that people couldn't reproduce his problem, so the title made the wrong impression I think.

I don't think that question is really salvageable.  Either there should be an obvious duplicate, or they should be pushed toward a basic text, since it's effectively language tutorial level.

Titles should ideally introduce the problem and give some information on what is being asked, @CarlColijn . A title that boils down to "Give me advice about python" doesn't tell us anything, especially when the question is tagged with [[tag:python]]. Based on the content to the question, perhaps "How to make code more succinct and not repeat the same code multiple times?" may be better. Though, in truth, the question probably belongs on [codereview.se] instead. The code works, and the OP isn't looking to solve a problem they can't solve, but rather improve the existing solution they have.

@Craig Your last point was also something that went though my head.  And if the focus would be on the "writing better code" part then Code Review might be the better site I guess.

@ThomA : thanks, noted.

@CarlColijn Yes I think the reviews on the question you linked are ok. If there are changes to be made by the author, "Requires Major Changes" is the option you'd want to use.

As a last question to get myself comfortable: I'm tempted to whitelist this question as-is.  It's got a (probably?) working code example, asks a clear question I guess, but while I'm familiar with JavaScript I've no knowledge of ExtJS so don't know if this is a config or programming question.  And I'm uncertain if I'll be even able to do the correct searches to know if it's a duplicate at all.  I think missing to 'mark as duplicate' is the part I'm most uncertain about.

@CarlColijn You don’t have to be a subject matter expert on the question in order to review it. but it's certainly helpful. If you can't really look for duplicates, you don't need to (but it's good if you can). For that question, I could imagine more information on the project being helpful but I don't know that much about JS and JS frameworks either.

I skip most questions, but sometimes focus only on the most obvious things: if you find a question 'My app doesn't work, what should I do?' you'll definitely use the template "Be specific about your problem", and it doesn't matter whether you're an expert or not in that area

Next to both (current) Answers, one "quick way" to learn quickly how to do "good Reviews in the 'SG'", is from the 'SG - Review History', to filter on 'Approved' and/or 'Require Major Changes' and to "study" how experienced SG-Reviewers do their Reviews by looking at what kind op Posts end up being 'Approved', reading the Comments, and checking the Revisions/Edits of those Posts. // Experienced Reviewers would be (not limited to of course!) [dan1st + Abdul AB + Karl K + all Mods + ThomA + starball + quite a few more, easy to identify from their Comments/Answers in SG-Threads on 'Meta'].

@chivracq I disagree with looking at approvals in the review history being a good way to identify what should be reviewed. There are sometimes questionable approvals (especially users approving a lot of posts) from what I have seen so far.

@dan1st, I didn't say "Posts Approved by anybody", but only handled by the experienced Reviewers like yourself...

However, there is a thing you can do if you want to: You can follow a question after approving it (especially if you are unsure) and see what happens with the question. That might cause you seeing things you overlooked or similar. But don't worry too much about some of your approved questions being closed, you can't make everything a good question (and you may not know everything about the topic).

This is a very good question and applies to other review queues as well. A bit of domain knowledge is actually tremendously helpful. What helped me was strictly filtering by tags and getting more domain knowledge and checking questions in a formal way (like checking a checklist: is it a debug problem, yes? Is there code attached? is the code minimal? ...).

As a start, I'd like to give a shout out to Guidelines and best practices for reviewers on the Staging Ground

Most questions are out of my comfort zone to triage (due to not knowing the underlying tech used),

See guideline #1, which is titled "If you know what a good question looks like, you can review anything". At least according to whoever wrote it (Yaakov).

and for the ones left over I'm either reluctant to press accept since it might be a duplicate (how to find out?),

You could try to search for a dup-target. But I do think recognizing a dup-target can take subject-matter expertise, so I personally wouldn't sweat looking for dups for anything you're not familiar with.

potentially off topic (config problems should go to superuser I suppose?), or already declined where I see room for improvement but where I hesitate to take action, since I know I'm often too lenient and try to help out people anyway.

I wouldn't generalize config problems like that. If it's config of a programming tool, I think it's on-topic. Ex. I answer a lot of questions about VS Code config.

So I processed lots of questions with a 'Skip', apart from one where I felt reasonably comfortable the question was genuine, of a high enough quality and not off-topic. So I felt pretty useless afterwards.

I wouldn't worry too much about it? As many here say, "there's no shame in skipping".

I then went to the staging ground review history and saw some other users working through the queue in parallel with me, and they mostly just declined most questions (for various reasons, but mostly off-topic).

That raises eyebrows for me, actually. Most stuff in my experience is not "off-topic" in the staging ground sense of the word.

Are these other persons just all-knowing gods and should I gid gut on all possible tech out there so I can give fast and appropriate feedback too? Or should I just not feel intimidated by the process and the possible consequences of mislabeling a question? Or should I just stick to a tag I'm most familiar with and only review questions for that tag?

If you want to grow as a more general reviewer, keep reviewing more generally. If you want to stick to your tags, then stick to your tags. It's up to what you want. The review guidelines are very helpful to read if you haven't already. I feel like they should ease your concerns.

On top of the official Help Center document, you may be interested in Reviewing in the Staging Ground: A practical guide .
It's fine to skip questions you don't know how to review - just as it would be in review queues. But your experience in the Staging Ground will be much nicer, IMO, if you don't treat it like a queue. Instead, go to the main Staging Ground page (https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground) and use the filters at the top to filter questions according to tags where you have expertise. For example, I almost exclusively look at Python questions, even though I would be qualified to review typical questions about quite a few other programming languages.
Regarding duplicates: recognizing duplicates just comes with experience with a specific topic, which is a good reason to filter by tag. But this is really the same as main site curation - you probably are just new to the idea of explicitly putting on the "curator" hat. You can find duplicates the same way we expect the OP to have looked before asking: by using the site search or an external search engine (perhaps adding something like site:stackoverflow.com to the query. If you approach questions from the perspective that beginners' problems result from things that beginners do all the time, you'll find that you can categorize those things in your mind a lot more easily. Over time, you'll identify that you've used (or at least looked for) certain duplicate targets repeatedly; add common duplicate targets to your Saves, then you can add in:saves to your site search queries. It helps a ton.
In my experience, most questions (the overwhelming majority) "Require Major Changes" but are perfectly well on topic. Familiarize yourself with the comment templates, the standards for closing questions on the main site and the purpose we uphold by not compromising on those standards.
There are pockets of the SG review community that are definitely overusing the "off-topic" closure reasons. My guess is that people feel more pressure to select "Not reproducible or caused by a typo" when "needs debugging details" isn't available to them - but this is missing the point of the Staging Ground. To be clear: while the site software on the main site considers that a closed question is a closed question, in principle some questions could be fixed while others can't. The distinction between the close reasons, fundamentally, is that "not reproducible" signals that attempting to give an MRE would immediately betray that OP needed to be more careful and does not actually misunderstand anything - i.e., there is not an MRE of a problem that actually needs explanation. Since there is no meaningful question, it cannot be fixed. Whereas, if a question needs debugging details, it's simply that the MRE has not yet been given. Giving it would fix the question; therefore, it can be fixed.
In the Staging Ground, if an MRE is missing, there is a corresponding "Include an MRE" template. You should use this, and then review the question as "Requires Major changes". However, more generally, a different template, or even a custom message, may be more appropriate. You should try to guide the OP based on your understanding of what makes a question suitable for the site, regardless of your assessment of the question's difficulty or your own ability to answer. For example, I have my own template comment for questions that are blatantly just dumping code and requesting debugging:
Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write
answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific**
question - which will come out of your best attempt to 
[understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and 
[locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and
showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack
Overflow is one where you have already figured out the
**specific part** of the code that does something different from
what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*),
and don't understand why.


Note regarding (tag or similar) filters: If a filter is active on the SG main page, it also applies for the "review queue mode".

The other answers here already answer the substance of your question, but I wanted to contribute a supporting suggestion:
There is a chat room Staging Ground Discussion / Support where you are welcome to bring up your concerns in real time.
I'm not currently a regular in the room myself, but I know I learned a lot about curation just by hanging out in another chat room for discussion about potentially low-quality questions, SOCVR
For the record, you need 20 reputation points to participate in chat.
In the words of meditation teacher Dan Harris, never worry alone.

It is required to have 500 reputation to review questions in the Staging Ground so I guess the 20 rep requirement shouldn't be an issue for anyone feeling overwhelmed with reviewing.

Good addition; I already stumbled into it via a comment of @dan1st on my question and it's a good resource to use too.

Apart from what was said already, a good place to start might be to ask yourself:

What would I do I encountered this post on the main site and why?

Would you downvote or close it? Why? If you would, that's probably a reason to write a comment asking the author to edit their question to change whatever issue you would have with the post and then use the "Requires Major Changes" option (If the post is not about programming at all or similar, the off-topic option might still be appropriate but NOT for clarification, formatting or similar issues).
The next useful question to ask yourself could be:

Do you think this post could be answered given only the information present in the post? If not, why?

If the post cannot be answered, it probably needs to be edited by the author ("Requires Major Changes").
Once you think a post is on-topic, there aren't any necessary improvements to make left (especially considering these questions), you probably to consider approving it.
